# Are birchat hoda'ah on the idea or the thing?

Tags: blessing

There are brachot said on phenomena and events. According to the instructions in the Artscroll, one says the lightning/thunder and rainbow blessings no more than once each day *unless clouds dissipated and then returned*. In that case, they can be said more often. The remaining blessings are said no more than once in every 30 days.

If the remaining blessings (earthquake/comet, the ocean, beautiful things, strange looking things, a Torah scholar, a secular scholar and a gentile king) are made on the idea (a king, like the notion of a thunderclap thunder storm) then I can understand not saying it again, but if the blessing is on the specific iteration (as it appears by the exception regarding a new thunderstorm) then would the same exception be made for the other blessings?

If I see both the Atlantic and Pacific oceans during the same day, or see two different strange looking animals an hour apart, is that like two separate thunder events or does the 30 day rule hold true.

Comment: Atlantic and Pacific are two sides of the same ocean. How about Superior and Galilee?

Comment: While you interpreted the exemption on a new blessing on thunder in the same storm as an example of the same object not needing a new blessing, you could also conceptualize it as multiple thunder objects which don't need a new blessing since the first covers all without interruption. Once the storm ends then your focus on the storm ends and so does your blessing. This explain the new day rule for a storm that spreads multiple days. A corollary would be saying a blessing on a king at the UN and then seeing many more during your visit.

Comment: @DoubleAA re: Superior and Galilee, I am just using the examples given in the Artscroll, which names only those particular bodies of water (therefore I didn't suggest other "oceans").

Comment: The Artscroll you're quoting is for שעשה את הים הגדול, right?  Other big bodies of water get עושה מעשה בראשית, so the question is still relevant to them.

Answer (score 7):

[Shulchan Arukh OC 224:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.224.13?lang=bi&with=Magen%20Avraham&lang2=en) rules that you don't make the blessing again if you see *that thing* again within 30 days (emphasis added). Most later authorities (eg. Magen Avraham, Mishna Berura, Arukh HaShulchan ibid.) understand this to mean that if you were to see a different king within 30 days you would still say a blessing.

Comment: It can be challenging to pin down the unit of "thing" for certain blessings. Do new graves in the same cemetery count? Meteors in a meteor shower? A mountain peak a mile away in the same range?  But these are details.